# PDFKit: Render pdf from html with table

Tags: swift, macos

I am creating a pdf from html by converting the html to `NSAttributedString` first and then rendering it to a `PDFDocument`.

This works fine, except for the fact that for some reason **tables are not being rendered correctly**.

Here's the `NSAttributedString` I get from the html:

```
This should be a table:
{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Bold 24.00 pt. P [] (0x7f90ac739460) fobj=0x7f90ac738e80, spc=6.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 16.08, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 1 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}Foo
{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x7f90ac721ff0) fobj=0x7f90ac7337d0, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n    \"<NSTextTableBlock: 0x6000021d2100>\"\n), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}Bar
{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x7f90ac721ff0) fobj=0x7f90ac7337d0, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n    \"<NSTextTableBlock: 0x6000021d0c80>\"\n), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

I am not an expert on `NSAttributedString` by any means, but my understanding is that the table data blocks are rendered correctly, aren't they?

Here's the resulting pdf, **which just puts the table data beneath each other, ignoring the table row they should be in**:

[image]

Here's my code:

the html:

```swift
let html = """
<h1>This should be a table:</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>"
```

the rest:

```swift
let pdfData = try self.renderPdf(from: html)
let pdf = PDFDocument(data: pdfData as Data)

func renderPdf(from html: String) throws -> NSData {
        guard let htmlData = html.data(using: .utf8) else {
            throw CocoaError(.coderInvalidValue)
        }
        
        let pdfNSData = NSMutableData()
        guard let pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumer(data: pdfNSData as CFMutableData) else {
            throw CocoaError(.coderInvalidValue)
        }
        
        let margin: CGFloat = 20.0
        let paperSize = CGSize(width: 595.0, height: 842.0)
        var mediaBox = CGRect(x: -margin, y: 0, width: paperSize.width, height: paperSize.height)
        guard let pdfContext = CGContext(consumer: pdfConsumer, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil) else {
            throw CocoaError(.coderInvalidValue)
        }
        
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] =
        [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]
        
        let attributedStringFromHtml = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
        let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedStringFromHtml)
        
        var pageRange = CFRange()
        
        CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRange(location: 0, length: attributedStringFromHtml.length), nil, CGSize(width: 595.0, height: 842.0), &pageRange)
        
        let pageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: paperSize.width - (2 * margin), height: paperSize.height - margin)
        
        
        let framePath = CGPath(rect: pageRect, transform: nil)
        let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, pageRange, framePath, nil)
        
        pdfContext.beginPDFPage(nil)
        CTFrameDraw(frame, pdfContext)
        pdfContext.endPDFPage()
        
        return pdfNSData
    }
```

**What am I missing here?**

#### Edit:

To learn more about `NSAttributedString`, I fired up a Playground and put an attributed string together with a manually built `NSTextTable` like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa

let table = NSTextTable()
table.numberOfColumns = 2

func makeCell(row: Int, col: Int, text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let textBlock = NSTextTableBlock(table: table, startingRow: row, rowSpan: 1, startingColumn: col, columnSpan: 1)

    textBlock.setWidth(4.0, type: NSTextBlock.ValueType.absoluteValueType, for: NSTextBlock.Layer.border)
    textBlock.setBorderColor(.blue)

    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.textBlocks = [textBlock]

    let cell = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text + "\n", attributes: [.paragraphStyle: paragraph])

    return cell
}

let content = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "some text")
content.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n")) // this newline is required in case content is not empty.

//If you append table cells to some text without newline, the first row might not show properly.
content.append(makeCell(row: 0, col: 0, text: "c00"))
content.append(makeCell(row: 0, col: 1, text: "c 0 1"))
content.append(makeCell(row: 1, col: 0, text: "c 1 0"))
content.append(makeCell(row: 1, col: 1, text: "c11"))
```

This seems to work in my point of view:

[image]

Comment: Well, that's the thing: I am really inexperienced in working with `NSAttributedString`, but I do see that my table cells are wrapped in a `NSTextTableBlock` (see the `NSParagraphStyle` property on the two cells) – so it seems to ma that it should be aware of the concept of tables, should't it?

Comment: I added infos on working with `NSTextTable` to the post above.

Comment: I played around with this some more and found an interesting open source package that does what I need: [https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF](https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF) – I will start looking into this and try and figure out how it's being done there. Looks really promising.